# How can I use Python to go into Outlook and list the date received of emails with certain subject name?

Tags: python, email

I want to use Python to give me a list of the dates emails were received that have a specified subject.

For example, if I have the subject name "Data extract", I want the Python script to give me a list of dates received of emails with this subject.

So far I have managed to log in to Outlook using Python but I can't seem to find a way to read the contents in the account.

```
import imaplib
import email

userName = "myname@companyname.com"
passwd = "password"
imap = 'imap.outlook.com'
inbox = "Inbox/Data"
sender=''
print("Connecting to Mail Server")
m = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap)
typ, accountDetails =m.login(userName, passwd)
m.select('"{}"'.format(inbox))

subject_name="HotelName_Data"
```

Comment: If you are in a corporate environment it is likely that your sysops will be unwilling to give 3rd-party programs like yours access to the Exchange message store. You can discuss it with them, but in my experience they are unlikely to be sympathetic.

Comment: We have a lot of other Python scripts that we use to access data received via emails and download. I just need to know how to search by a specific subject name @BoarGules

Comment: You're lucky, then.